# Avoid NodeJS module "require" duplications

Tags: node.js, require

I have multiple NodeJS files in a `/libs` folders, for example:

`math.js`, `restapi.js`, `auth.js`, `push.js`

whereas `math.js` is the class that provides basic math functionalities and all the `restapi.js`, `auth.js`, `push.js` need `math.js`.

The problem is that I have so many `require './math.js` in all other classes, for example:

```
    // In auth.js
    var Auth = new function __Auth(){
        function A(){
            var math = require "./math.js";
            return math.fooA();
        }

        function B(){
            var math = require "./math.js";
            return math.fooB();
        }
   }

   exports = module.exports = Auth;
```

In `app.js` (the main app)

```
var math= require('./math.js');
math.getConfig('config.json');

var auth= require('./auth.js');
console.log(auth.fooA());
```

In `app.js`, the base class `math.js` must first call `getConfig()` to initialize necessary variables and constants from the configuration file. (thus, I want to keep just ONE instance of `math.js` and it's okay as it's the default NodeJS behaviour).

(Notice this is just an example to simplify the actual codebase).

I know that NodeJS has a caching mechanism with `require`, but does it means that a having `require math.js` for each single function call is the only way to do? I think it's so expensive and non-optimal.

In other language (for example, PHP), there could be a single `require` on top, and no `require` for each single function to reference to the same class.

Any recommendation for a better & **more efficient** code design?

PS. I've just edited the question a little bit to clarify the situation.

Comment: Seems like a circular dependency problem or something similar. We will need to see `math.js` to give a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

auth.js

```
var math = require ('./math.js');

function A(){
    return math.fooA();
}

function B(){
    return math.fooB();
}

function C(){
    return math.fooC();
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to correctly describe the result. The problem is that in the main app, `math.js` must call `getConfig()`, and by `require math.js` at the beginning of the class as you describe, it will return an error.

Comment: `var Auth = new function __Auth(){
    var math = require('./math.js');
    this.A=function(){ return math.fooA();}; // ERROR, math is not defined
}

exports = module.exports = Auth;`

Comment: requiring math on top of file app.js does not make it available on auth.js. you need to send math variable to auth.js too to make it available in auth.js. May [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39671888/1200882) explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your module at the top of your file. It's not necessary to include it in each function. And don't be afraid, this approach is not a sign of bad code style.
Also it's good practice to import all libraries at the top of file that is used by a current module.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate your math on app.js and require auth with math parameter included in it.

```
// In auth.js
function __Auth(math){
    function A(){
        return math.fooA();
    }

    function B(){
        return math.fooB();
    }
}

exports = module.exports = function (math) {
    return new __Auth(math);
};
```

your auth.js will use math from instance initiated from app.js

```
// In app.js
var math= require('./math.js');
math.getConfig('config.json');

var auth= require('./auth.js')(math);
console.log(auth.fooA());
```

Please let me know if it work or fail.